# naming conventions in game code / vocabulary

Tags: software-engineering

I'm just starting out as a game developer, and I'm finding some difficulty when naming classes.

I usually call the class that handles everything `World`, `Map`, or `Grid`. Then there's the names, inside.

---

For example, I'm making a Frogger clone, and I have a class for everything that moves on screen (I try to use MVC and I'm talking about the model here - I have `Sprite` classes in the view), and I named it `Object` for lack of a better name. Then there's a subclass from `Object` which I named `Frog` (though I could name it `Player`)  and another one for the things controlled by the computer, which I don't know what to call (it could be `Enemy` or `Obstacle` or something appropriate for cars and trucks). This class also includes the turtles, which are more like helpful objects, yet are not powerups.

---

How should I manage my naming conventions?

Comment: Game code is no different from "real life" code, any OOA/OOD reference is good.

Comment: *Entity* is a slightly better name than *Object* as the latter is normally a reserved keyword or at least implies top level container for all objects in a codebase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're having trouble naming things it's probably because your class design itself is messy.  Just hearing you talk about your code it seems like you're overusing inheritance.

Also, there are a ton of questions on here about MVC and generally speaking it isn't a good pattern to try to force into things.  Gaming is more like Model view viewmodel than mvc anyway.

I don't think there's a specific reference for what you're looking for.  Also, in general SE sites are better if you ask specifically what you're looking for instead of a reference for what you're looking for.  For example, draw out your specific class hierarchy and ask what might be the best way to name your obstacles-that-also-can-be-useful, or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Tetrad is correct that your ideas seem a bit messy at the moment.  But to answer the question more directly (small picture rather than big picture) for those who come hereafter:

Typically you want a few classes with a lot of properties, rather than subclasses.  [Here's a wikipedia reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) someone gave me when I asked this exact same question like 4 days ago in a chatroom.  (Thanks Alex, for helping me find it again).

For example (of what not to do): Among the entities we've got `Frog`, `Truck`, `Land`, `Water`.  Land and Water are stationary, or static.  Frog and Truck are moving, or dynamic.  So we could make `Static` and `Dynamic` subclasses and put each one into those classes.  On the other hand, both a Truck and the Water will kill you.  Maybe Water is Dynamic, instead?  Water and Truck are both in the `Enemy` class?  Well... no.

It's better to use properties on the various entities.  `Frog` and `Truck` have the `canMove` property.  `Truck` and `Water` have the `killOnContact` property.

**To Clarify and make Direct** You'll find that it's easier to come up with names for the behaviors and features and what not, than it is to come up with a single category in which something should go.  (The same reason each SE site has tags rather than categories).

Comment: My apologies.  I did not mean that I asked it on an SE site.  I asked in a chatroom full of programmers, informally, and got directed to a reference site.  Also figaza's question was regarding the naming of classes and subclasses and subclasses of those subclasses, and I suggested that the asker instead use properties.  Through personal experience, the first step to naming something is to figure out where in the hierarchy it should go.

Comment: The other downvote probably comes from the fact that what you're suggesting is not a good idea. A lot of people will suggest to get away from inheritance, they'll suggest [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) to avoid messy inheritance trees, which can become real hells to work with.

Comment: But that is literally what I was saying!  Move away from inheritance (subclasses) and towards composition (properties that add behavior).  Also, funny enough, that is the page I had looked at and couldn't remember where I had seen it.  Should I edit my answer to say "For example (of what not to do):"?

Comment: The answer is better now.

Comment: IMO, the main issue I found with this answer still remains. Despite the impression that you are "answering the question, directly" there is far more explanation of structure than actual naming convention. I feel this would confuse or offput users.

Comment: As a compromise, I would be content removing my dpwnvote if the answer made attempts to answer the question *first*. You can then go into further structure analysis *at great length*; users who are detracted at this point still receive the main answer content. I would make the change, myself, but I feel I would not properly retain the intent of your answer.

Comment: At any rate... I'll deal with this in the morning.  It's about 3 hours past the time I should be going to sleep.

Comment: +1 for the TL;DR section in the end. I agree, the intro is rather confusing.